# resizing of thumbnails not working

Tags: functions, post-thumbnails

i have the following in my functions file from the wordpress codex

```
<?php add_filter('show_admin_bar', '__return_false');
if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) {
add_theme_support( 'post-thumbnails' );
    set_post_thumbnail_size( 150, 150 ); // default Post Thumbnail dimensions   
}

if ( function_exists( 'add_image_size' ) ) { 
add_image_size( 'category-thumb', 300, 9999 ); //300 pixels wide (and unlimited     height)
add_image_size( 'homepage-thumb', 220, 180, true ); //(cropped)
};  ?>
```

And the below to call the thumbnail in my custom loop

```
<?php if ( has_post_thumbnail() ) { the_post_thumbnail( 'category-thumb' ); } ?>
```

However it doesnt seem to be resizing the thumbnails. Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 1):

This may be because thumbnails of all image sizes not generated,try [Regenerate Thumbnails](http://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/)

**Important Link**:

[How to Regenerate Thumbnails or New Image Sizes in WordPress](http://www.wpbeginner.com/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails-new-image-sizes-wordpress/)

Comment: yea but this is a new size image, so it shouldnt matter?

Comment: I updated my answer please go threw blog post as i mention.WordPress generate all image size thumbnail when you upload image.So all image which are already in media library have not all image sizes thumbnail,to generate you have to use regenrate thumbnail plugin

Comment: @Kirsty Harris try regenrate thumbnail plugin,clear your browser cache.hope all works good.

Comment: Hi Ravs, As i said, this is not the same image, this is a new image that uploaded as the featured image, so therefore surely it should generate a new thumbnail anyways?

Comment: when you define your image size before upload image or after upload image.if you define image size after upload image it should not generate thunbnail of all image size.regenrate thumbnail plugin do not harm your media library you should give it a try.if it is not work then seem to be other problem.